# mounting remote c: drive in cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin

I'm using cygwin

how do i mount a remote c: drive in cygwin

to mount a remote shred dir one could use

mount //#ip address#/#shared folder#  /#new dir#
but trying to mount c: drive fails

mount //#ip address#/C$ /#new dir#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to escape the dollar sign:

```
mount //#ip address#/C\$ /#new dir#
```

or

```
mount "//#ip address#/C$" /#new dir#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the remote drive as a drive letter in Windows, you can then navigate to /cygdrive/<drive letter> within cygwin.

If you need to mount the drive from the command line, you can use "net use". type "net help use" for command line options.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this option since i have another application that map the this drive but with different credential